# backstretch and idle-timer - making them worth together

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch, idle-timer

I'm using the [backstretch.js](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) jquery module to make a background slideshow.

Now, what I want to do is add in the [jquery idle-timer](https://github.com/mikesherov/jquery-idletimer), and have it interact with some of backstretch's elements.

I've got a piece of code working, which shows and hides certain elements based upon what item I'm on.

The Backstretch code is like this and works:

```
var images = [
    "/images/01.jpg",
    "/images/02.jpg",
    "/images/03.jpg"
];

// The index variable will keep track of which image is currently showing
var index = 0;

// Call backstretch for the first time, and increments the index instance.
$.backstretch(images, {speed: 500});
//immediately pause the slideshow
$('body').data('backstretch').pause();

$(window).on("backstretch.show", function (e, instance) {
     if (instance.index === 0 ) {
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#next').show();
    } else if (instance.index === instance.images.length - 1) {
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#next').hide();
    } else {
        $('#prev').show();
        $('#next').show();
    };
});
```

On the first picture, it shows only the 'next' button. On the last, only 'prev' button. And on the rest, both buttons.

The Idle-Timer code looks like this (and it works too). It hides the nav buttons after five seconds, and then shows them when you touch the page again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).idleTimer( 5000 );
        $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#prev").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#next").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#prev").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#next").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

When showing the first picture, you'll see only the next button, then wait and the button will hide. Then move the mouse and the next *and* prev button is shown by the second part of the idle-timer.

So I think I want it to look something like this (which doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).idleTimer( 5000 );
        $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#prev").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#next").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
        if (instance.index === 0 ) {
            $("#next").fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (instance.index === instance.images.length - 1) {
            $("#prev").fadeIn(1000);
        } else { 
            $("#prev").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#next").fadeIn(1000);
        };  
    });
});
```

Though, this gives me an error about the index not being defined. So can I break the index & instance.index out into global variables for the idleTimer to access? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using fadein/out in backstretch, I made that first script add and remove a class (i used ".showme") depending on which slide it was on.

That showme class is just a `display:block;` and I set the elements to have a default of `display:none;`

And then the idletimer script refers only to that one class to fadeIn/Out.

Not perfect, but it does work. Without having to try to fish the instance out into a global variable.